# Can't set status bar from action hover slot in Pyside2/Qt 5

Tags: hover, qt5, tooltip, statusbar, pyside2

I want to show a tool tip in the status bar when hovering an action that is in a menu.

I am trying this since I could not find a way yet to show a tool tip when hovering.

However, I am not able to set the status bar from the hovering slot/event/callback either. Everything is being called, but it seems to have no effect, other than clearing the status bar.

Here is a minimum working example:

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QStatusBar

app = QApplication([])

# Create a main window
main_window = QMainWindow()

# Create an action
action = QAction("My Action", main_window)

# Add the action to the main window's menu bar
main_window.menuBar().addAction(action)

# Create a status bar
status_bar = QStatusBar(main_window)
status_bar.showMessage("Initialized.")
main_window.setStatusBar(status_bar)


# Define a function to update the status bar with tooltips
def update_status_bar():
    if action.isEnabled() and action.toolTip():
        status_bar.showMessage(action.toolTip())
    else:
        status_bar.clearMessage()


# Connect the hover events to the status bar update function
action.hovered.connect(update_status_bar)

# Show the main window
main_window.show()

# Run the application event loop
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the `hovered` signal has precedence, and then it is emitted *before* the status tip event is triggered.

Since the action's status tip is empty, the result is that, even if the status message is set by `update_status_bar`, it will instantly be cleared by the empty status tip.

The simple solution is to *explicitly* set the status tip:

```py
action = QAction("My Action", main_window, statusTip="My Action")

# alternatively:
action = QAction("My Action", main_window)
action.setStatusTip(action.text())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer just made realize that I was complicated things a lot because I was setting the `ToolTip` attribute on QtDesigner, which sets `toolTip`. I didn't even notice that there would be another field `statusTip`, which is the one I need to set.